# Import button class not working in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

First of all, I did setting-> auto import -> change ask to all, and tick unambiguous. 
I typed

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

and it turns to grey, and can't use button method.

Comment: paste the code for button instantiation and its click along with layout.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the comment. However I am new(1 day) to Android Studio, and where is 'button instantiation and its click' code, and what does 'along with layout' mean?

Comment: Welcome to Android. Please follow the basic tutorials for Android from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html  OR https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/  Follow the guidelines and if possible watch youtube videos to understand about android. I will suggest you to get first basic ideas about android then start coding which is quite easy to do.

Comment: First of all in Android `Button` is _not_ method it's a Class. When you use modern IDE's like Android Studio, Eclipse or Netbeans you don't have write `import android.widget.Button` manually simply `Button` you will get auto completion for `Button` import just select it that's it.

Comment: It's funny, but thank you your comment reminded me that is "B"utton, and problems are solved. ......